# Symbol Gets Stuck on Edge Occasionally

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some code whereby I want a symbol (just a square atm) to bounce around inside the stage. Occasionally however, it gets stuck on the edges. Any advice on how to fix this?

Everything else works fine, including the inertial motion.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*
    import flash.ui.Keyboard

    public class Unit extends MovieClip {

        var velocityX:Number = 1;
        var velocityY:Number = 1;
        var accellerationX:Number = 1;
        var accellerationY:Number = 1;
        var bounciness:Number = 1;
        var maxSpeed:Number = 10;

        public function Unit(){ 
            Key.initialize(stage);
            addEventListener("enterFrame", move);

        }

        private function move(e:Event){

            accellerate()
            if ((this.x<10)||(this.x>780)){
                velocityX *= -1;
                    if (velocityX>0){
                    velocityX -= bounciness;
                }
                if (velocityX<0){
                    velocityX += bounciness;
                }
                this.x += velocityX;
            }
            else{
                this.x += velocityX;
            }
            if ((this.y<10)||(this.y>520)){
                velocityY *= -1;
                if (velocityY>0){
                    velocityY -= bounciness;
                }
                if (velocityY<0){
                    velocityY += bounciness;
                }
                this.y += velocityY;
            }
            else {
            this.y += velocityY;
            }
        }

        private function accellerate(){

            if (Math.abs(velocityY) < maxSpeed){
                if (Key.isDown(Keyboard.UP)){
                    velocityY -= accellerationY;
                    trace("Accellerating UP");
                }
                if (Key.isDown(Keyboard.DOWN)){
                    velocityY += accellerationY;
                    trace("Accellerating DOWN");
                }
            }
            if (Math.abs(velocityX) < maxSpeed){
                if (Key.isDown(Keyboard.RIGHT)){
                    velocityX += accellerationX;
                    trace("Accellerating RIGHT");
                }
                if (Key.isDown(Keyboard.LEFT)){
                    velocityX -= accellerationX;
                    trace("Accellerating LEFT");
                }
            }
            if (Key.isDown(Keyboard.SPACE)){
                velocityX = 0;
                velocityY = 0;
        }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is like the following:

```
if ((this.x<10)||(this.x>780)){
    velocityX *= -1;
```

You toggle the volocityX, but what is likely happening is on the next frame, it still meets the if condition (hasn't moved far enough the other direction) so it's just going back and forth every frame from -1 to 1.

Do something like this instead:

```
if(this.x < 10 && velocity == -1) velocity = 1;  //If it's near the left edge, and still moving to the left, change direction
if(this.x > 780 && velocity == 1) velocity = -1;
```

This way, you are only flipping the direction when it's going the wrong way.

Repeat for the velocityY stuff

Comment: Thanks, that's done the trick! I thought that might be the issue, I just couldn't think how to actually fix it, I've even gone so far as to completely rewrite the acceleration function to use direction boolean selections xD thank god I'm using GitHub and can easily revert. Thanks again!

Comment: Yea, a decade or so ago I remember this same thing driving me crazy for a few hours (no stackoverflow then).  Glad you didn't spend too long on it!

Comment: I've just tried this: 'if (((this.x<10) && (velocityX <0)))||(((this.x>780) && (velocityX >0))){' but I'm getting errors out the yazoo...  Like:  1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before logicalor. sorry to keep bothering you... but what's wrong with that?

Comment: Extra parenthesis is what, or rather one in the wrong place.     `if (((this.x < 10) && (velocityX < 0)) || (((this.x > 780) && (velocityX > 0)))) {`

Comment: Ahh brilliant, now I've got rid of that, all I'm getting is "else is unexpected" so presumably that can never evaluate to false for some reason? I really appreciate your help btw!

Comment: That means you have `else` somewhere that doesn't belong - perhaps a wrong of missing curly brace.  I'm off SO for the weekend in a few minutes so I won't be able to help further until Monday.  Send me your GIT link and I'll take a peek if you're quick

Comment: Just had a look and I've managed to totally screw the repo... so I'm gunna have to debug it now, don't worry about it, I'll see what I can do. Thanks so much for your help though.

Comment: Fixed it, was just a missing curly brace